# How to run Firefox on a Debian server

Tags: firefox, ssh, gtk, debian

I have installed Firefox on my Server (running Debian 6.0) but when I try to launch it I get the following message:

```
Error: no display specified
```

After googling I installed *xvfb* and now I have this error;

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99.0".
```

and it freezes.

Can anybody help me?

Update: I'm now able to run Firefox, but I don't want it to open up a local window but everything should be done on the server side. It should just open up, play a macro (made with iMacros) and then shut down. The opening and the closing will be handled by a script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting with SSH to that Debian machine? Then call next time the ssh-command with -X as argument, this will pass the correct display options to the server.

Comment: Thank you. Firefox is now launched (I can see it when I list the processes) but it doesn't show up. Is there a way to see the firefox window. I actually want to install add-ons, so if there is a way to do it without opening a window let me know.

Comment: It is hard to say this since I have no clue about your home machine... Have you checked out Google already? Using the keywords firefox AND install add-on AND remote I get some quite good answers...

Comment: OK I just had to wait about a minute (as I have a slow connection) to see a local window open up with the Firefox running on the server. Now I want the opposite. As FF is really slow this way, I want to launch it on the server. It should just open up play a macro (made with iMacros) and then shut down. The opening and the shutdown will be made via a script. I'll edit my post.

Comment: I think this next question is worth another topic itself. So don't edit the post but post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Launch this from your box's xterm:

```
ssh -X debian-server dbus-launch firefox
```